# force the use of rpm -U after first install of pkg

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a pkg that contains configuration files for my application that gets updated 6 times a year.

The very first time ever the pkg is installed I want the sysadmins to install it with `rpm -i mypkg-1.2-0.rpm`

However on each subsiquent install I want to **force** the sysadmins to run it with the Upgrade switch `rpm -U mypkg-1.2-1.rpm`

What do I need to put in the rpm .spec in order to ensure that the rpm -U switch **must** be used ?

Comment: Can I ask *why*? `rpm -U` can be used on a never-installed-before RPM anyway. And what about a new machine? Are you going to have two releases of the same RPM, one for new machines and one for upgrades?

Comment: I want to have one pkg but every if the install option is used each time then the rpm db looks like this:
mypkg-1.2-0
mypkg-1.2-1

Comment: Pretty sure you have to go out of your way to install multiple copies of an RPM that aren't explicitly written to handle it, e.g. `kernel`, but I don't have the info right now.

Answer (score 1):

The place to look is the `%pre` tag.  According to [Chapter 13. Inside the Spec File](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html) of Maximum RPM

> When the first version of a package is installed, its `%pre` and `%post` scripts will be passed an argument equal to 1.

The Fedora [packaging page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:ScriptletSnippets) elaborates, saying that you can detect the difference between install and upgrade by checking if `$1` is 1 or 2, respectively.  Reading closely the comment

> Note that these values will vary if there are multiple versions of the same package installed (This mostly occurs with parallel installable packages such as the kernel and multilib packages. However, it can also occur when errors prevent a package upgrade from completing.) So it is a good idea to use this construct:

```
%pre
if [ $1 -gt 1 ] ; then
fi
```

makes it seem as though you should be cautious in case *your* package allows multiple versions to be concurrently installed.

Comment: What you wrote is true but when I do the intial install with rpm -U $1 equals 1 so your method would allow me to force -U on the subsequent install only. This means that I would have to get everyone to install a base pkg then go for the upgrade pkg instead of just giving the updated pkg for everyone. thanks for your help